# how to set nodespacing in timeline layout

Tags: gojs

I am working on gojs timeline sample(http://gojs.net/latest/samples/timeline.html) which is by default functionality based on dates.I have added more number of nodes to existing nodes due to that they are overlapping each other.
then how to set nodespacing in this layout.

Answer (score 0):

in the prototype code in the example, you find this part, which you could rewrite:

```
var bar = line.findObject("BAR");
      var length = 100;
      var cellw = 100;
      if (bar && numweeks > 0) {
        length = bar.actualBounds.width;
        cellw = length / numweeks;
        // set the size of each cell
        bar.gridCellSize = new go.Size(cellw, bar.gridCellSize.height);
        // offset to account for starting on a non-first day of the week
        bar.gridOrigin = new go.Point(convertDateToX(firstsunday), bar.gridOrigin.y);
      }
```

here you have three options (actually two, 3. is only a suggestion):

1. **change the `var`s**:

   ```
   var length = /*the length you want the bar to have (you could take the number of cells * the cellw below)*/
   var cellw = /*the length you want each cell to have*/
   ```
2. **make it configurable**:

   do something like

   ```
   TimelineLayout.prototype.setCellW = function(newcellW){
   this.cellW = newcellW;
   }
   ```

   then reference it in the part shown above.
3. **Use a GridLayout instead**: 
    look [here](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/gLayout.html) to see if that would be sufficient for your needs.